# How can I create a history log every time I update a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form where I can update my data in the datagridview and it will save a log.

My problem is that every time I saved my data it insert all the data in the datagrid.

How will i save data that will only save if i made changes to the datagridview? is that possible?

Here is a snapshot of my UI:

[image: Datagridviewsample]

And my code code that saves the data:

```
//this is the formula for inserting history logs
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=" + clsSQLcon.sqlServerName + ";port=" + clsSQLcon.sqlPort + ";Initial Catalog =" + clsSQLcon.sqlDatabaseName + ";user id =" + clsSQLcon.sqlUserName + ";password =" + clsSQLcon.sqlPassword + "");
conn.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO tblhistorylogs(DATE_UPDATED,NAME,LOGS) VALUES" +
    "(@Date,@Name,@HistoryLogs)";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (txtPRSSearch.Text.Length <= 3)
    { }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Updated by: " + LoginForm.SetValueForText1 +"\n("+ cbxPRSctrl.Text + "-" + txtPRSSearch.Text +")");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HistoryLogs",
      
          "STATUS: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) + "\n" +
          "ITEM NAME: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value) + "\n" +
          "DATE RECEIVED: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) + "\n" +
          "RECEIVED BY: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) + "\n" +
          "SUPPLIER: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value) + "\n" +
          "PO/PCF/PIS: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) + "\n" +
          "UNIT COST " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value) + "\n" +
          "AMOUNT: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value) + "\n" +
          "REF/CV/JV: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value) + "\n" +
          "DATEPAID: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value) + "\n" +
          "INCHARGE: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value) + "\n" +
          "TARGET DATE: " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value));

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [DataGridView Event to Catch When Cell Value Has Been Changed by User](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19537784/3744182).  Or, alternatively, if you were to bind to a `DataTable`, does this answer your question? [Return only the changed rows of a datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25060745/3744182)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use a DataTable for the DataGridView DataSource working with DataTable method [GetChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.getchanges?view=net-6.0).

To see an examples see the following GitHub [repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataTablesOperationsEvents). The core code is in the following [class](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataTablesOperationsEvents/blob/master/BaseLibrary/ExtensionMethods.cs) using extension methods. Note that the code presented is not a direct drop-in and use but provides the basics for you to adapt to your task.